# Python loop through ndjson file data

Tags: python, json, for-loop, jinja2, ndjson

I have `ndjson` file `Patients.ndjson`

```
{"resourceType":"Patient","id":"ewnMwMK-UNvVvM.bakFSlkw3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-NullFlavor","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"},"url":"ombCategory"},{"valueString":"Unknown","url":"text"}],"url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-race"},{"extension":[{"valueString":"Unknown","url":"text"}],"url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-ethnicity"},{"valueCodeableConcept":{"coding":[{"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.10.698084.130.657370.334258","code":"female"}]},"url":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/extension/legal-sex"},{"valueCodeableConcept":{"coding":[{"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.10.698084.130.657370.334258","code":"female"}]},"url":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/extension/sex-for-clinical-use"},{"valueCode":"F","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-birthsex"}],"identifier":[{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"EPIC"},"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.5.737384.0","value":"E9254"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"EXTERNAL"},"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.2.698084","value":"Z11363"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"FHIR"},"system":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/patient-dstu2-fhir-id","value":"TYO3ktvhYAUhbae7JuBwDdpyIbUZc8kZG.bMW2ZwVnwgB"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"FHIR STU3"},"system":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/patient-fhir-id","value":"ewnMwMK-UNvVvM.bakFSlkw3"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"PAS"},"system":"urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.12.1.1","value":"2005294"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"INTERNAL"},"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.2.698084","value":"    Z11363"}],"active":true,"name":[{"extension":[{"valueCode":"NL4","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-assembly-order"}],"use":"official","text":"Test ADVANCEPREPTWO","family":"ADVANCEPREPTWO","given":["Test"],"_family":{"extension":[{"valueString":"Advancepreptwo","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-own-name"}]}},{"extension":[{"valueCode":"NL4","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-assembly-order"}],"use":"usual","text":"Test ADVANCEPREPTWO","family":"ADVANCEPREPTWO","given":["Test"],"_family":{"extension":[{"valueString":"Advancepreptwo","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-own-name"}]}}],"gender":"female","birthDate":"2006-10-07","deceasedBoolean":false,"maritalStatus":{"text":"Single"}}
{"resourceType":"Patient","id":"exU8JSL0p8npSw5g1QYAyOw3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-NullFlavor","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"},"url":"ombCategory"},{"valueString":"Unknown","url":"text"}],"url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-race"},{"extension":[{"valueString":"Unknown","url":"text"}],"url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-ethnicity"},{"valueCodeableConcept":{"coding":[{"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.10.698084.130.657370.334258","code":"female"}]},"url":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/extension/legal-sex"},{"valueCodeableConcept":{"coding":[{"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.10.698084.130.657370.334258","code":"female"}]},"url":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/extension/sex-for-clinical-use"},{"valueCode":"F","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-birthsex"}],"identifier":[{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"EPIC"},"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.5.737384.0","value":"E9340"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"EXTERNAL"},"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.2.698084","value":"Z11449"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"FHIR"},"system":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/patient-dstu2-fhir-id","value":"TwzgMHMPt5OhnHkFA2H2DudL3FU8qcRZkZyn0F3extkAB"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"FHIR STU3"},"system":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/patient-fhir-id","value":"exU8JSL0p8npSw5g1QYAyOw3"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"PAS"},"system":"urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.12.1.1","value":"2005380"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"INTERNAL"},"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.2.698084","value":"    Z11449"}],"active":true,"name":[{"extension":[{"valueCode":"NL4","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-assembly-order"}],"use":"official","text":"BcnScTenAugTwentyOne UPGRADETEST","family":"UPGRADETEST","given":["BcnScTenAugTwentyOne"],"_family":{"extension":[{"valueString":"UpgradeTest","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-own-name"}]}},{"extension":[{"valueCode":"NL4","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-assembly-order"}],"use":"usual","text":"BcnScTenAugTwentyOne UPGRADETEST","family":"UPGRADETEST","given":["BcnScTenAugTwentyOne"],"_family":{"extension":[{"valueString":"UpgradeTest","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-own-name"}]}}],"gender":"female","birthDate":"2019-09-21","deceasedBoolean":false,"maritalStatus":{"text":"Single"}}
{"resourceType":"Patient","id":"ezER-U3fAMP-WvI-Fc8V9wQ3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-NullFlavor","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"},"url":"ombCategory"},{"valueString":"Unknown","url":"text"}],"url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-race"},{"extension":[{"valueString":"Unknown","url":"text"}],"url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-ethnicity"},{"valueCodeableConcept":{"coding":[{"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.10.698084.130.657370.334258","code":"male"}]},"url":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/extension/legal-sex"},{"valueCodeableConcept":{"coding":[{"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.10.698084.130.657370.334258","code":"male"}]},"url":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/extension/sex-for-clinical-use"},{"valueCode":"M","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-birthsex"}],"identifier":[{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"EPIC"},"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.5.737384.0","value":"E9411"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"EXTERNAL"},"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.2.698084","value":"Z11522"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"FHIR"},"system":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/patient-dstu2-fhir-id","value":"T2oDrcOUw0w.1ZUdthu24c7V95lTOTEOUPRqBqGn99KEB"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"FHIR STU3"},"system":"http://open.epic.com/FHIR/StructureDefinition/patient-fhir-id","value":"ezER-U3fAMP-WvI-Fc8V9wQ3"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"PAS"},"system":"urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.12.1.1","value":"2005452"},{"use":"usual","type":{"text":"INTERNAL"},"system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.520.3.7.2.698084","value":"    Z11522"}],"active":true,"name":[{"extension":[{"valueCode":"NL4","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-assembly-order"}],"use":"official","text":"Fred TEST","family":"TEST","given":["Fred"],"_family":{"extension":[{"valueString":"Test","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-own-name"}]}},{"extension":[{"valueCode":"NL4","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-assembly-order"}],"use":"usual","text":"Fred TEST","family":"TEST","given":["Fred"],"_family":{"extension":[{"valueString":"Test","url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-own-name"}]}}],"telecom":[{"system":"phone","value":"07594 832748","use":"mobile"},{"system":"email","value":"fred@email.com"}],"gender":"male","birthDate":"1967-01-19","deceasedBoolean":false,"address":[{"use":"old","line":["123 Anywhere"],"city":"Bristol","postalCode":"BS1 6JY","country":"ENG"},{"use":"home","line":["123 Anywhere"],"city":"Bristol","postalCode":"BS1 6JY","country":"ENG","period":{"start":"2022-01-19"}}],"maritalStatus":{"text":"Single"},"communication":[{"language":{"coding":[{"system":"urn:ietf:bcp:47","code":"en","display":"English"}],"text":"English"},"preferred":true}]}
```

I am opening ndjson file and trying to loop through the dictionaries to pick all the patient's `id`,  `birthDate` and `deceasedDateTime`

**Python Code to read ndjson file**

```
import ndjson 

 with open('Patients.ndjson') as f:
   data = ndjson.load(f)
  return render_template('home.html', patient =  data)
```

**Html Template**
This for loop displays all the items and values in html page.

How do i only pick specific values `id`,  `birthDate` and `deceasedDateTime` from the given dictionaries?

```
{% for i in patient : %}
{% for item, value in i.items(): %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ item }}</td>
         <td>{{ value }}</td>
      </tr>
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [section about variables](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#variables) for jinja2, you only need a small change:

**main.py**

````py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import ndjson 


app = Flask(__name__)


template = "tmp.html"


@app.route('/')
def main():
    with open('patients.ndjson') as f:
        patients = ndjson.load(f)

    return render_template(template, patients=patients)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)```
````

**tmp.html**

```
{% for patient in patients %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ patient.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.birthDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.deceasedDateTime }}</td>
    </tr></br>
{% endfor %}
```

### EDIT

As an FYI, when loading an ndjson in python, it becomes a list of dicts. In your template, you need to iterate over the list, and for each dict item get the correct value by using the key as shown in my example.

You could use `dict.items()` but this gives you all the key/value pairs unordered...

fe, using the following will print out the whole JSON for each line in the NDJSON:

```
{% for patient in patients %}
    {% for key,val in patient.items()  %}
        {{ key }}: {{val}}</br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks i tired your suggested change but this just showing empty html page  i am not seeing any result.

Comment: I was just testing myself, and the provided ndjson is not a valid ndjson. Can you provide a valid ndjson?

Comment: I have added a 4th line in the ndjson file above which is a complete ndjson that i am receiving from api.

Comment: I updated my answer, I changed the variable names as this was what threw me off at first. Please always use meaningfull variable names as it becomes a lot easier to read. The code above worked on the updated ndjson. Note that the 3 examples do not have a `deceasedDateTime ` so I'm not sure if that works, but my example should allow you to fix this...

Comment: that did the trick. thanks so it should have been  patients = patients ?

Comment: that doesn't matter that much, if the variable name in your python code (eg the `patient-data` part) matches the variable name in your template, all's good.